# Fragment Runtime Exception Debugging

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm a bit new to Android development, but am working on an application with a relatively large code base that loads in a library that does JNI calls. When calling a library method, in my fragment, a Runtime Exception is thrown due to an error in interfacing with JNI, which causes a crash (the pop-up window "Unfortunately, APP_NAME has stopped.") but doesn't actually stop the application; enabling it to be used in a *broken* mode in which assets and other parts aren't loaded properly in my ViewPager.

I'm wondering if this is common behavior for Runtime Exceptions in Fragments?
I'd prefer for the whole application to just crash and not enable this *broken* mode; but haven't had enough experience with Android to know if this is intended behavior or not.

I've tried using the Android Studio debugger after the crash occurs but it appears the debugger stops which is understandable behavior because the application should have terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like your app is handling such exceptions, you might be interested to look into something like this in your work space:

```
 private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new      Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
     public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
         Log.e("TestApplication", "Uncaught exception is: ", ex);
         // log it & phone home.
          androidDefaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
     }
 };
```

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to be the case, the exception was being caught and rethrown to try and recover the application, but leaving it in a broken state.